# Ubuntu 20.04 executing 'update-grub' failed while installing

Tags: partitioning, grub2, system-installation, uefi

***What happened:***

I originally had this problem:
*[After installing ubuntu 20.4 from live session, while rebooting getting different errors each time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233410/after-installing-ubuntu-20-4-from-live-session-while-rebooting-getting-differen)*. I did not get any answers there so...

***What I tried:*** while trying to fix this problem I figured out that this might be related to improper partitioning while installing. I had two prominent issues while installing Ubuntu.

1. executing install-grub failed
2. efi partition not found... (while installing without efi partition)

I tried fixes online with my partitioning tables like:

ref: *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sqj1r9BY3mQ*

ext4 mount-point - / 200000Mb

biosgrub 512Mb

Selected biosgrub partition and continued... (Here the installation crashed without specific error message)

ref: *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwXRtJ6eC7I*

ext4 mount-point - / 200000Mb

swap area (half the size of my RAM) 4000Mb

efi 512Mb

Selected efi partition and continued... (Here I got executing update-grub failed error)

***Current situation:*** I still don't have any OS installed and would like to run Ubuntu 20.04 on my system. I have access to Ubuntu 20.04 boot media. I tried finding answers online, surprisingly no where update-grub error was found.

***Request:*** I am not that professional yet!, I would like answers in simple language and in step format so I can follow along. Any advice regarding the matter will be helpful too...

Thank you for helping in advance !

Comment: The bios_grub is only for BIOS installs to gpt partitioned drives. You do not want that. And it is only 1MB if using BIOS. But you have to have ESP - efi system partition and 512MB is a good size. With Ubuntu you do not have to have swap partition as it now uses swap file. 40,000 MB is 40GB, you may only need 2 or 4GB.  If you have it, it will auto find it and use it unless you say do not use. Only boot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI boot mode.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: @oldfred I read the article you mentioned and corrected my typo (Swap size was actually 4000Mb). Installation did not go as planned though. each Installation steps took almost 10min to complete and while installing there was error : The efi partition file system creation in partition ... failed !

Comment: Is drive gpt partitioned? I prefer to partition in advance, and use Something Else to choose which partition is / (root). With gparted, Select gpt under device, advanced over msdos(MBR) default partitioning before starting. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation  &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: @oldfred Just as you said I made the changes from gparted and than tried again. Problem this time is the installation steps are taking too much time. After each step I have to wait for like 10 mins. gparted also kept scanning for like 10min. When I first installed Ubuntu using the same usb nothing like this happened, it was a smooth process. I checked my disk for errors but the disk smarttests shows ok for everything! Today installation failed without any specific error. It took me almost 45min to configure the installation setup. surprisingly installation went smoothly and crashed.

Comment: While it does take a minute or two to scan & find partitions, it should not take that long. My install once partitioned from ISO in RAM to fast SSD is under 10 minutes. Even install to HDD is only a little over 10 minutes. And the find partitions seems like the slowest part of install. Corrupt partitions/formats, Windows hibernation, wrong settings in UEFI (AHCI?) and some others can make it slow. My 2006 laptop with 1.5GB of RAM ran for two days with full ubuntu and never worked, but only took under an hour with server installer.

Comment: @oldfred Can you please list down the settings (BIOS) and other things I need to check. I also find this issue quite unusual. First time when I installed ubuntu on my system It took me just 15min for entire installation process.

Comment: @oldfred I have posted a new question regarding this issue in more detail and how it exactly happened and more information about my settings will you please check that question out and help there. here is the link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235618/ubuntu-20-04-installation-problem thank you.