# Ubuntu 20.04 Installation Problem

Tags: system-installation, 20.04

### What I did

I wanted to clean install Ubuntu 20.04 system on my machine which previously ran windows 10 on it. This is what i did:

1. Downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 iso from my windows 10
2. Downloaded Rufus from my windows 10
3. Made fat32 boot-able usb (16Gb) for Ubuntu
4. From boot menu I selected the UEFI partition of Ubuntu pendrive
5. Without a delay I was taken to Ubuntu installation setup
6. I clicked on install Ubuntu (with English language selected)
7. Again selected English for keyboard layout.
8. Software and third party tab I clicked continue
9. I selected do something else
10. I deleted all the partitions of windows (I forgot to delete one partition of windows recovery environment as I thought it was pointing to my windows istallation media)
11. created the usual Ubuntu partitions efi and root
12. selected efi partition and installed the system.
13. System worked fine! Everything was good!

At this time though my PSU was malfunctioning. (Monitor screen would fluctuate by going into power saving mode) My windows system used to crash to because of PSU problem so I switched to light weight Ubuntu system. System was working fine but when I restarted it after putting in username and password my PC would go into power saving mode (PSU problem). I tried rebooting for 2-3 times but same problem. I Could not replace the PSU (Because of lock down!) so I removed my GPU to reduce power requirements. On the next reboot though there were no fluctuations in monitor screen but I just got a Blank screen with a '_' (Single underscore) On it. So I decided to reinstall Ubuntu!

1. I plugged in the same USB stick which I used before
2. In the boot menu selected UEFI partition of the USB
3. This time Instead of taking me to the installation setup directly I had this command lines on my screen: *https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP8gh.jpg*
4. After some loading I was on Ubuntu installation setup page.
5. As usual selected setup language as English
6. when I clicked next on keyboard layout tab (English was selected) setup loaded for 7-8min
7. On the next tab the setup just kept loading!
8. So I hit the reset button on my CPU
9. After again loading and loading I selected Try Ubuntu
10. Again there was this: *https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEvqi.jpg* screen! and after some loading Live session started.
11. I Started setup Again from here.
12. It took me 30min to reach to something else step of Installation (each step took 10min to load)
13. After that For making each partition It took 5-6Min
14. Installation luckily started and I had I/O Error. I clicked retry and everything looked good.
15. suddenly Installation stopped with executing update-grub failed error.
16. I started gparted and it kept scanning disk!
17. I performed Smart Data and self test this was the result: *https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhanN.jpg* (OK)
18. When I try installing again IT gets stuck on the third party software indefinitely!

All I have right now is Ubuntu installation media. I don't think now the PSU is at fault as There are no fluctuations. Here are my BIOS settings (I don't know that much but I thought I should list these) : *https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oQ2i.jpg*: *https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8A2W.jpg*: *https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0ajI.jpg*: *https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlYiI.jpg*: *https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrKzP.jpg*:

As I have no system installed currently and doing everything on live session please tell me what should I do accordingly. Also I am not a pro! please help because I cannot find proper answers online regarding my current situation. Thank you!

Comment: If bad PSU best thing is to try to replace before using computer.  To keep using might cause more hardware problems leading to replace whole computer.  Any chance of buying online and have shipped, seeing your stores are probably closed/limited access.

Comment: @crip659 I asked people I know who are into repairing computers for PSU. They said currently all the shop owners are closed and they are threatening to reopen stores (in lock down) if online electronics sale starts again. LOL! He said they can still sell me PSU but I have to pay extra (More than 60% of original price). So I thought I would just wait for the lock down to end ! :(

Comment: It is tough, but computer hardware has limited range of power it can take.  A bad PSU will make things worst and no OS will fix.  Know here most stores are closed also, but they allow people to phone in orders to be pick up at door.

Comment: What model Gigabyte? Some need boot parameters. If you uninstalled a video card, you needed to just uninstall the proprietary video driver, it does not always know not to use it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/792012/nvidia-geforce-gtx970-problem-ubuntu-16-04 I have a z170 Gigabyte and have had no real issues, but only use cpu's video. My then new Asus motherboard would not boot with an older power supply, that supposedly was per spec. Microcenter ran on testbench, worked without issue, so they sold me new power supply.

Comment: @oldfred I have Gigabyte H110M-S2. I didn't actually uninstall video card drivers, I just removed it from my CPU plugged into motherboards output. Video is working fine! While reinstalling this card I will have to again install the drivers !:D I do not have a powerful PSU mine is 'Circle CPH698 400 Watts PSU' and I Have 1050ti GPU. I have used this combination for 4years now. When I bought the GPU it said that I did not need powerful PSU but after digging online I think I should have had at least 550V good PSU. cauz now when I think about it my windows 10 started crashing while gaming year ago

Comment: Have you updated UEFI to latest available from Gigabyte?

Comment: @oldfred I just bought my new motherboard (Older one the same model was corrupted) like 2months ago. I have never tried updating UEFI. I would like to though. Will you just tell me how to as (I have never done it before :P) we will be on same page then.

Comment: With my Gigabyte I just go to the support page for my model board. Often have to search to find it. Then download the update file & save to a FAT32 formatted partition, I use my ESP or a flash drive. UEFI can only read FAT32, so then from Within UEFI, select update file. Compare to version you have installed currently.

Comment: @oldfred I did what you ask me to do. It was quite difficult slow and frustrating but I finally updated my BIOS! But everything else is just as it used to be. Still installation crashes with disk errors :(

Comment: Do you have UEFI Secure boot on? It may be "Windows" or "Other" and you want Other. And are drives set for AHCI, not RAID nor Intel RST? And are you using nomodeset on linux line? https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI if no Windows skip those screens but see the rest: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: @oldfred yes I have checked my BIOS settings it is just as you said. I have even put up my BIOS settings photos on the post.

Comment: A few have uninstalled GPU, installed with default video that chip provides (if you chip has that) then installed video driver & reinstalled GPU video card.

Comment: @oldfred Thank you for helping me man... keep up the good work!

Comment: @crip659 I did as you said and got a new PSU in the lockdown and finally everything is working. Thank you man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my PSU to cooler master msw white 650W this solved my graphic card and power issues. The main problem, which I thought was my Hard drive. Even after checking my hard drive using different software everything was showing fine. The problem was the SATA cable! I changed it to new one.